# Where to put websocket clients for a proxy in Akka.NET inside or outside Actors?

Tags: c#, akka.net

I am new to Akka.NET. I am building some kind of websockets proxy, I want to use Akka.NET for processing (transforming and forwarding) of the incoming traffic by using its actor system. But I am wondering what the best way is to do this.

Questions I have are:

- Should I create the main listener outside the Actor and instantiate an actor for every incoming “listening” client? Or should I put my main listener also inside an actor?
- Should I create the forwarding and transforming logic together with the “sending” websocket client also inside an Actor (Maybe a child actor of my previous question ;-) )? Or should I keep my client outside the actor and put it inside the Akka.NET message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@frankhommers so I've been working on an application that consumes a real-time feed using WebSocket and passes the parsed messages onto an Akka.NET cluster.

The approach I've taken for this can be summarized as:

1. Implement the WebSocket consumer as an [Akka.Streams Source](http://getakka.net/articles/streams/builtinstages.html#source-stages). Akka.Streams provides a highly composable and performant API for doing things like deserializing, filtering, and transforming messages coming off of the websocket and it's able to handle downstream backpressure via buffering too. You can find some examples of third-party implementations of Akka.Streams Sources for things like Azure Service Bus et al here: https://github.com/AkkaNetContrib/Alpakka - that should help give you an idea how to implement one yourself.
2. I launch my `Source<string>` as a [`ClusterSingleton`](http://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-singleton.html), which guarantees that there will be exactly one copy of my WebSocket consumer in the cluster at any given time. This source will eventually broadcast its results to several actors elsewhere in the cluster who will process the deserialized messages and do other stuff wiht it.

If you haven't gotten into Akka.NET clustering yet, don't sweat it - you can introduce that capability later after you've become more familiar with Akka.NET. But the goal of the design is to provide a reasonably high degree of consistency by having a just single consumer of the feed and having it simply broadcast its results elsewhere via Akka.NET's own messaging capabilities.

Comment: Is your application open-source, so I can take a peek? Or do you know of another example using WebSockets explicitly?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: I understand the Akka.Streams Source is the way to go, but I have no clue on how to start on this project. Maybe Akka.NET is not for me yet for this purpose. Thx.

Comment: Here https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/akka-streams/src/examples/TcpEchoService.Server/Program.cs I find the listener being created inside an actor. Would you advice against this?

Comment: You could do that too, although that code pre-dates Akka.Streams